# CentOS 6 Binding IP Addresses

Tags: networking, centos, ip, centos6

I can't seem to get IP binding to work properly. I have two files:
ifcfg-eth0 and ifcfg-eth0:1 (tried 0:0, 0:2 and still not working).

eth0 is supposed to be for IP 192.168.1.3 and eth0:1 is for 192.168.1.4.

After I create the files, I restarted networking. When I use ifconfig, it only shows eth0. If I try to ifup eth0:1, ifconig still only shows eth0 but with the eth0:1 IP.

Shouldn't it show both eth0 and eth0:1?

What am I doing wrong?

Here are the files:
ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none    
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=192.168.1.3
USERCTL=no
IPV6INIT=no
PEERDNS=yes
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

ifcfg-eth0:1

```
DEVICE=eth0:1
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=192.168.1.4
USERCTL=no
IPV6INIT=no
PEERDNS=yes
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

I did not include the hardware address.

Comment: At first glance nothing, have you tried a service network restart?

Comment: Yes, I have used that and restart the whole machine. Each time it just seems to load eth0. If I manually push eth0:1, it just replaces the IP shown in eth0 using ifconfig (doesn't modify the actual file).

Comment: That is odd, I've had the exact same problem, but only when I had identical names in the files..

Comment: Please append the output of `ip addr show`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network manager could be preventing this from coming up properly.

In each config file can you add the following line:

```
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

I have seen a few instances where this has caused trouble in the past.

Comment: This seemed to work. I am not seeing both interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify, at the top of the ifcfg-ethX file, the name of the interface. You probably just copied the eth0 file, and left the eth0 "name" at the top.

Comment: I have the intefaces set to the name of the file. I will add the files to the question.